# Azure Java SDK - set block blob to cool storage tier on upload

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

Is there a way to set the storage tier to “cool” at the blob level when uploading a block blob to Azure Storage using the Java SDK? The closest thing I can find is setStandardBlobTier() on BlobProperties, which is a protected method, so it can't be accessed.

Comment: Hi, any updates?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for the Java SDK, either, and I don't think there currently is one. I'll upvote your answer since it does provide a workaround via a REST API, but I'd rather wait for the Java SDK to catch up before implementing something since it's not a big issue for us to put off implementing this feature.

Comment: Yes, I can't agree more. I noticed that none of the SDKs currently supports modifying the StandardTier attribute, not just the Java SDK. I suggest you commit a feedback :https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback.

Comment: If any progress , please share with me. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [CloudBlockBlob](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlockBlob.html) now has two uploadStandardBlobTier() methods which can be used to set the blob tier on a block blob on a standard storage account. e.g.

```
cloudBlockBlob.uploadStandardBlobTier(StandardBlobTier.COOL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched the [Azure Storage java SDK source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/b796935916c4cdea261e17e9522cd64f3db93feb/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobProperties.java#L627) and `setStandardBlobTier()` method is protected method. I tried to create subclass of the `BlobProperties` Class and overwrite the `setStandardBlobTier()` method, but `BlobProperties` Class was decorated with the `final` keyword.

I also searched [Azure Storage c# SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.standardblobtier?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobProperties_StandardBlobTier), only `get` method was found.
It seems you cannot set blob tier via sdk , however you can set tier via [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier).

You could refer to the sample code as below:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SetBlobTier {

    private static final String account = "***";
    private static final String key = "***";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String urlString = "https://" + account + ".blob.core.windows.net/***/***?comp=tier";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
        getFileRequest(connection, account, key);
        // connection.connect();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }

    public static void getFileRequest(HttpURLConnection request, String account, String key)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        String stringToSign = "PUT\n" + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                + "\n"// content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                + "\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n" // range
                + "\n"
                + "x-ms-date:" + date + "\n"
                + "x-ms-version:2015-02-21"+"\n" // headers
                + "/" + account + request.getURL().getPath(); // resources
        System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
        String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);
        request.setRequestMethod("PUT");

        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-access-tier", "Archive");
        request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);

    }

    private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
        String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.